# Rename columns based on first line of the dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working on a ADF pipeline and I am on the last step of the DataFlow transformation but I am dealing with a dynamic column rename.

Basically I have a task that is creating a surrogated key in order to identify the rownumber with the column names that I need to use:

[image]

The rownum = 1 (first row in the image) has the names that I need to replace, let's say Column_1 should be renamed to "Org_Ind", Column_3 to "Indicador" and so on, but I have used a Derived column and I do not know how to create the expression, for now I have this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source dataset is File from Blob storage or ADLS you have the option called first row as header. You can select it and it will convert it as header.

[image]

**In Other conditions**

- we need to create dataflow parameter array of first row values
  `array('Org_lnd','Indicador','1/1/2022','2022-02 01','3/1/2022','202244-01','1')`
  [image]
- After this take Filter transformation after Surrogate key and filter the rows ehere key is not equal to 1 `Surrogate_key!=1`
  [image]
- Then in derived column mapp the accordingly with parameter array index
  [image]

***Output***

[image]